# shifting elements in fixed sized list

Tags: python, list, psutil

I have a list with fixed size of 10 which i will put CPU percent of my computer with 2 seconds of interval. ***What i'm trying to do is,
removing 1st element
shifting each element into previous index of list
recording 11th value at last index of list***

Below you may see my code. I did some debugging but i'm confused right now. How can i fix this?

```
__author__ = 'tim'
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import psutil, os, time

def getCpuRate():
   myList = [None]*10
   myString=" "
   myString2 = " "
   i = 0
   j = 0

   while True:
      if myList[9] is None:
         myList[i] = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=2)
         myString = myString + (str(myList[i]) + " ")
         i = i+1
         print i , myString
         #time.sleep(3)
      else:
         while i>0:
            myList[j] = myList[j+1]
            #print myList[j+1] , myList[j]
            for k in range(len(myList)):
               myString2 = myString + (str(myList[k]) + "")
            print i , j , myString2
            j = j+1
            i = i-1
            if j >= 9:
               myList[j] = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=2)
               print i , j , myString2
               j -= 1


print "a"
getCpuRate()
'''
mySecondList = getCpuRate()
for x in range(len(mySecondList)):
   print mySecondList[x]
'''
print "b"
```

Comment: if you only have 10 elements where does the 11th fit?

Comment: i'm trying to overwrite 2nd to 1st, then 3rd to 2nd and so on. Once 10th element is copied over 9th, i need 11th to be written over 10th

Comment: is this homework or can you simply use a deque? `from collections import deque deq = deque(maxlen=10)`

Comment: it's not a hw and i can use deque but i simply prefer not to :)

Comment: what about `if len(lst) > 10`remove first item?

Comment: I dont' get why you don't want to use a deque, because lists are not the best choice for what you have in mind, see documentation: "Though list objects support similar operations, they are optimized for fast fixed-length operations and incur O(n) memory movement costs for pop(0) and insert(0, v) operations which change both the size and position of the underlying data representation."

Comment: I agree with @SmCaterpillar. The deque is not only the adequate data structure but it also results in a very compact function. I see no reason not to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a [deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque)?

Just fill in 10 dummy values and then use `append` and `pop`. So everything gets *shifted to the left*. Or you specify the `maxlen=10` (maximum length) of the deque and only use `append`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a list you could use a `deque` ([documentation link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque)), which is a list optimized for the kind of operations you want.

```
import collections
q = collections.deque()

# add element at the end:
q.append('cpu percentage here')
# add element at the beginning:
q.appendleft('cpu percentage here')

# remove first element:
q.popleft()
# remove last element:
q.pop()
```

Then, you loop becomes much simpler:

```
import psutil
import collections

def getCpuRate():
    q = collections.deque(maxlen=10)
    while True:
        q.appendleft(psutil.cpu_percent(interval=2))
        print(q)
```

Notice that I the ordering so that we insert the new values at the beginning and remove the old ones at the end. This way the new values come first when printing `q`. If you don't want that, you can change `appendleft` by `append`and `pop` by `popleft`.

Comment: I have already asked the OP if they can use a deque and the response was *i can use deque but i simply prefer not to :)*